# Retrieve all rows from all database tables with "Where" condition

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I have a DB with 60 tables. In some of those tables I have a bit column named "Open" where I store a 0 if the record is not in use by an user (user access DB from a C# application) and an 1 if the record is in use.
Well, I need to get all the records from all the tables in my database where the "open" column value is true, or 1.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: do all your tables have the same columns?

Comment: no, but they have the "Open" column

Comment: I`m guessing you need dynamic sql,to loop over all tables with a certain column but I dont know how to do it.

Comment: sp_MSforeachtable might help. Or you could query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and build up a query string to execute with sp_executesql().

Comment: What is the point? What are you going to do with some number of rows from 60 tables?

Comment: If the application fails, electricity fails or other kind of problem that afects the "Open" state, I need to create a way to select all the rows that were open before the problem and then give the information of what rows (records) where affected by the problem, allowing the admin to restore the open state to 0.

Comment: You can UNION ALL the tables and create a view, but you must know wich are the tables with the Open Column.

Comment: @Reznor13 i'd like to help but i can't make a sense in this request... the technical solution is easy but the result is pretty useless. what's the expected result? 60 resultset with 60 different structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick piece of code that gets list of tables within your database.  Using a cursor loop through the answers checking it they have the fld named [open] and if it does the build a SQL statement and the execute this SQL string.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_BulkTableOpenReport 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @TBLS AS TABLE (REF INT IDENTITY (0,1), TABLENAME NVARCHAR(100), TABLEID BIGINT);
    DECLARE @TBL AS NVARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @TBLID AS BIGINT;
    DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @I INT = 0;
    DECLARE @M INT = 0;
    DECLARE @V INT = 0

    INSERT INTO @TBLS(TABLENAME,TABLEID)
    SELECT NAME,OBJECT_ID FROM sys.tables

    SELECT @M = MAX(REF) FROM @TBLS

    WHILE @I <= @M
    BEGIN
        SELECT @TBL = TABLENAME, @TBLID= TABLEID FROM @TBLS WHERE REF = @I 
        /* CHECK TO MAKE INSURE THAT A FLD CALLED [OPEN] EXIST. */
        SELECT @V = COUNT(*) FROM SYS.columns WHERE name = 'OPEN' AND  OBJECT_ID = @TBLID
        IF @V != 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @TBL + '] WHERE [OPEN] = 1'
            EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
        END;
        SET @I = @I + 1
    END; 
END
GO
```

From your c# application exec the query "EXEC usp_BulkTableOpenReport" then loop through the table outputs.

Comment: If you put this into a stored procedure, you can access this through C# with a simple call to this stored procedure " exec usp_show " and then within your C# application step through the result sets.

Comment: Hi Stephen, how can I put this into a SP?

Comment: Updated the original answer to be a stored procedure.  Now you can call it via SQL or C# by simply 'exec usp_BulkTableOpenReport'

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple use of the undocumented sp_MSforeachtable:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 
@command1='SELECT * FROM ? WHERE Open=1',
@whereand='AND o.id in (select object_id from sys.columns c where c.name=''Open'')'
```